# How to reset the table data to what it was before it was edited in template-driven form Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template

So I have a table of user data that is editable after clicking on the edit hyperlink. When it is pressed the cancel and submit buttons appear. Cancel should make it so that the row is no longer editable and any edits that happened in the table row get undone. My problem is that I don't know how to undo the edits.

Relevant html

```
<table #table class="table">
            <colgroup>
                <col width = "10%">
                <col width = "*">
                <col width = "20%">
                <col width = "20%">
                <col width = "20%">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class = "text-center" scope = "col">#</th>
                <th class = "text-center" scope = "col">First Name</th>
                <th class = "text-center" scope = "col">Last Name</th>
                <th class = "text-center" scope = "col">Sex</th>
                <th class = "text-center" scope = "col">Birthday</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of displayData; let i = index" >
                  <th scope ="row">{{ i + 1 }} </th>
                  <td [contentEditable]="isEditable && enableEditIndex==i" (input)="saveEdit($event, user.firstName); this.userNum=1"> {{user.firstName}} </td>
                  <td [contentEditable]="isEditable && enableEditIndex==i" (input)="saveEdit($event, user.firstName); this.userNum=2"> {{user.lastName}} </td>
                  <td [contentEditable]="isEditable && enableEditIndex==i" (input)="saveEdit($event, user.firstName); this.userNum=3"> {{user.sex}} </td>
                  <td [contentEditable]="isEditable && enableEditIndex==i" (input)="saveEdit($event, user.firstName); this.userNum=4"> {{user.birthday | date}} </td>
                  <td>
                       <button *ngIf= "this.enableEdit && this.enableEditIndex == i" (click)="cancel(); enableEdit=false; isEditable=false" class = "btn" >Cancel</button>
                       <button *ngIf= "this.enableEdit && this.enableEditIndex == i" id = "saveBtn" class="btn" (click)="submitEdit(i); enableEdit=false; isEditable=false" type = "submit">Save</button> 
                      <p> <a [routerLink]="" class="table-row-action edit-action" *ngIf="!enableEdit" (click)="enableEditing($event, i)">
                         edit
                       </a> </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Relevant ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.displayData = this.displayForm.users;
}
enableEditing(e: any,i: any){
        this.enableEdit = true;
        this.enableEditIndex = i;

        this.isEditable = true;
    
    }
    
    reset(){
    
        this.displayData = this.displayForm.users;
    
    }
    
    cancel(){
        this.reset();
    }
    
    saveEdit(event: any, name: string){
        this.editUser = event.target.outerText as string;
        this.editName = name;
    }
    
    submitEdit(index: number){
      switch(this.userNum)
      {
        case 1:
            this.displayForm.users[index].firstName = this.editUser;
            break;
        case 2:
            this.displayForm.users[index].lastName = this.editUser;
            break;
        case 3:
            this.displayForm.users[index].sex = this.editUser;
            break;
        case 4:
            let userDate = new Date(this.editUser);
            this.displayForm.users[index].birthday = userDate;
            break;
      } 
      
    }
```

Comment: Just create a copy of displayData and assign it into another variable.
If the user cancels, so, assign to the first variable, the value of the second one. 
You can clone the default displayData like: 

this.displayDataCopy = Object.Clone({}, this.displayData);

Comment: I would highly suggest you, have an edit button that will make the record editable and only after you click on submit it will be updated. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ant-editable-table-qzefns This might help you out.

Comment: @Anglesvar I try your method of implementing the editing and I get an error on this line: `this.editCache[id] = {data: { ...this.displayForm.users[index] }, edit: false` The error is  "Type 'User' cannot be used as an index type." So what do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: @MarcoAntonioMartinez Can you put the code in stackblitz and share the link?

Comment: @Anglesvar Ok here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v2xsk1?file=src/app/display-data.component.ts  Display data components are where you should focus your attention to.

Comment: @Anglesvar Nevermind I figured it out. I was missing a curly brace for one of the methods. Everything is running great now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On edit click, you can set a component variable to save the current state of that row. Then on cancel, reset it back to that saved variable.

```
tableList: any[] = [];
currentRowData: any <- user interface preferably

onEdit(rowData: any) {
 this.currentRowData = rowData
}

onCancel() {
 let item = this.tableList.find(x => x.rowID = this.currentRowData.rowID);

 if (item) {
  item = this.currentRowData;
 }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I'm getting an error saying that I can't assign currentRowData to item because it is a constant. What should I do about that?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the code. It should be 'let' not 'const'

Comment: So I tried it and it doesn't do what I was hoping. I click edit, I change something in the row, I press cancel and it doesn't undo the edit. Maybe I did something wrong. Am I supposed to pass template variable to the edit function?

Comment: No, your issue is what @Anglesvar mentioned. You should have 1 save button and not call an event on each input.